# Change scene from thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity3d project which contains 3 scenes.

I have a very basic web server written in C# in this project.

This C# class is attached as a compontent of the first scene.

This first scene is the scene we see when the application runs.

Here is what i want to do: I want to change the scene when a user call a specific URL.

I am using this code in my http server:

```
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("scene name");
```

I had an error because LoadScene should be called on main thread only.
So i have made some changes in order to put scene name in a variable.

Then, i call LoadScene in Update() method from this variable value.
I do not know if it is a good thing.

I have no error but the scene is not changing in game.

Thanks

** EDIT **

Here is my source code:

This first class is not associated to any scene (components):

```
public class ServeurWeb
{
    private Scene1 main;

    public ServeurWeb (Scene1 main)
    {
        this.main = main;
        var newThread = new Thread(thread_serveur_web);
        newThread.Start();
    }

    private void thread_serveur_web()
    {
        var listener = new HttpListener();

        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8084/");

        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = listener.GetContext();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => HandleRequest(context));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleRequest(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            var context = (HttpListenerContext)state;

            if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/scene1")
            {
                main.load_scene("scene1");
            }

            if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/scene2")
            {
                main.load_scene("scene2");
            }
            if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/scene3")
            {
                main.load_scene("scene3");
            }

            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello!");
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            var output = context.Response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This second class is attached as a component to the scene1, in a gameobject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Scene1 : MonoBehaviour {
    private ServeurWeb serveur;

    private string scene_active = "ecran_noir";

    public void load_scene(string scene)
    {
        this.scene_active = scene;
    }

    void Start () {
        serveur = new ServeurWeb (this);
    }

    void Update () {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name != scene_active) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene (scene_active);
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the project, i see Scene1.
If i call http://localhost:8084/scene2 in my browser, i can see scene2.
But, next, if i call any url, i can see a response in my browser (thread is alive), but scene2 stays on the screen

Thanks

Comment: `UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("scene name");
});`

Comment: Thanks but i think i have another problem: The code of my webserver is attached to scene1. When scene2 is loaded the code does not work...

Comment: 1.I don't know what your webserver looks like. 2.I can't tell what you mean by "does not work". Both of these combined together made it impossible to help you. Can you try a simple `UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() => {Debug.Log("Hello"); });` and see if you see the log in the Console tab?

Comment: Thanks for your help. See my edit with everything

Comment: Revert your code to what it used to be when you were getting the error "I had an error because LoadScene should be called on main thread only:. Now put call `UnityThread.executeInUpdate` from the main Thread to load new scene. `if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/scene1")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene ("scene1");
            }` then `if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/scene2")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene ("scene2");
            }`

Comment: and `if (context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/scene1")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene ("scene1");
            }`. You don't need the code in the `Update` function anymore. Remove that! `if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name != scene_active) {`